# Count the number of times going through a list from beginning

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve problem A (called Task Management) in the following website: http://codeforces.com/gym/101439/attachments/download/5742/2017-yandexalgorithm-qualification-round-en.pdf

Basically, we are given a unsorted list of integers from 1 to n and we want to visit integers in order(i.e from 1,2,3,4,5,.... n). How many times do we have to go to the beginning of the list until we have visited all integers from 1 to n in increasing order.

Let's say we have a list like: 3 2 1. during the first run through the list we visit only the number 1, during the second run through the list, we visit only the number 2, and during the third run we finally visit the number 3. So we have to go through the list 3 times.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class TaskManagement{

// arr: array of tasks
static int countNumberOfLoops(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    int targetTask = 1;
    // Last task to close
    int finalTask = arr.size();
    int index=0;
    int count =0;

    while(targetTask != finalTask+1){
        if(index%arr.size()==0) count++;
        if(arr.get(index%arr.size())==targetTask) targetTask++;
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    // make a static array of size n
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int item = scan.nextInt();
        arr.add(item);
    }

    countNumberOfLoops(arr);
}
}
```

The problem is: my code is not efficient enough, **O(n^2)** and for a very large data set, it will be slow.

Is there any way I can implement the code in a more efficient way?

Comment: Why not use a sorting algorithm to sort the input? Sorting unsorted lists without extra information works in `Omega(n * log(n))`. Or did I missunderstood your problem? What exactly is the input and what the expected output?

Comment: Let's say we have a list like:   3 2 1.   during the first run through the list we visit only the number 1, during
the second run through the list, we visit  only the number 2, and during the third run we finally visit the number 3. So we have to go through the list 3 times.

Comment: Let me rephrase, for me it sounds like you want to sort a given list and your sorting algorithm works in `O(n^2)` however there are better sorting algorithms that work in `Omega(n * log(n))`, for example *Quicksort* or *MergeSort* or *HeapSort* and so on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms. So why not just implement one of these.

Comment: The goal is not to sort the list. The goal is to count how many times do we have to go through the list from beginning to the end, until we have visited all numbers in increasing order.

Comment: What exactly is the model? Is random access allowed? I ask because you are given an `ArrayList` which allows random access, so `list.get(i)` is possible. Or does your model only allow you to iterate from start to end and not all over the place at random? Or are you allowed to continue at a position where you already where, like a `LinkedList` would allow (and `ArrayList` also). If you are only allowed to iterate from start to end, then of course there is no better solution and `[3, 2, 1]` yields 3 iterations...

Comment: Well, you could use random access, it wouldn't be really useful since we have to keep track of how many times we have gone through the list until we have visited all numbers. You could use other data structures like linkedList.

Comment: Consider this example: 1 3 2 5 4 .     In first iteration we visit 1 and 2. In second iteration, we visit 3 and 4 and in third iteration we visit 5. So in total we have gone through the list 3 times.

Comment: Just iterate the input from left to right. Each time you see a value that is lower than the value before, you count one up. In the end the counter shows the amount of iterations you would need. This works in `O(n)` obviously. In your  example `[3, 2, 1]`, you first see `3`, then `2` which is lower, so counter increases. Next comes `1`, again lower than `2`, counter increases. Initialize the counter with `1` and it will now show `3`, the result.

Comment: To wrap it up again: Basically you are allowed to use any technique, no restrictions to solve the problem. The problem is to find out how often the presented algorithm starts all over again.

Comment: @Zabuza  Your understanding is correct but your approach wont work for a case like: 3, 5, 2, 4, 1.   In this case you have to iterate 4 times. But I'm thinking if I can find a similar approach to yours .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Loop through all the numbers and store the index of their occurrence in a hash table or a normal array since numbers are between 1-n.
   For example if, the numbers were 3, 4, 5, 2, 1
   which would result in hash like this. (let's call this Index)

   {
   1 -> 4,
   2 -> 3,
   3 -> 0,
   4 -> 1,
   5 -> 2
   }
2. Loop from 1 to n-1 and find the index for ith and (i+1)th element.

loopCount = 0;

```
loopCount = 0;
for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    if (Index[i] > Index[i+1]) {
        loopCount++;
    }
}
```

Time complexity O(n)

Comment: Your solution actually works but your loop count must be initiated as 1 instead of Zero. Because in the case of 1 2 3 4, you only go through the list once without incrementing loop count.

Answer (score 0):

An editorial has been posted [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/51789):

> Consider a solution with the complexity O(n^2). Use a variable to track the
> last closed task and go through the list of tasks from the beginning
> to the end. Increase the counter when passing through the element
> corresponding to the next task. The constraints are quite large, so
> this solution doesn't fit the timelimit.
>
> What is the case when we can
> not find any suitable tasks up to the end of the list? There is only
> one case: the task number (x + 1) is closer to the beginning of the
> list then the closed task number x. Therefore, to solve the problem we
> can determine position of each task in the task list and count the
> number of distinct numbers x such that the position of task number
> (x + 1) is less than the position of task number x.
>
> Don't forget to
> consider the first pass through the task list. The final complexity of
> the solution is O(n).